# Explain output of program

Tags: c++

Could you help me explain output of following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = "%s";
    printf(str, "Hello K\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello K
```

**My explanation:**

The statement `printf(str, "Hello K\n");` is replaced by `printf("%s" , "Hello K\n");`and so the output is `Hello K`. Is this correct?

Comment: `str = "%s";` is not a valid C++, so this should not compile. Also this actually looks more like a plain C program.

Comment: Yes. What is not clear?

Comment: follow up from VTT answer: you should write `const char *str = "%s"`

Comment: it is not really clear what is the aim of this exercise, if it is to print "Hello K" on the screen you could do `std::cout << "Hello K\n";` if it is to understand what `printf` does, did you try to consult some reference?

Comment: @VTT: It compiles still in both GCC and Clang, sadly, unless you have `-Werror`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this code is C. 
Second, **how format string works?**
When you call a function (in any language I know) you allocates the arguments on the stack, and then call the function which intial the base and stack pointers and starts to run.
Format string functions like `printf` calculates the offset to the right string based on the number and order of the arguments.

So when parsing the first argument, **whether it comes form local variable like in your code, or its a constant string from the `.data` section**, it looks for `%` chars and for each one it calculates the address to right argument, relatively.

To prove this point, try to use `printf` with just one argument: `"%s"`, and you will see some value on the scrren, this is the place in the stack where the second argument should have been. Really cool stuff, we call it *Format-String-Attack*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct.

`str` is a variable that stands-in for what could otherwise be achieved with a string literal.

However, please be made aware that it should be a `const char*` — that `const` is important as it ensures that you will not attempt to modify the contents of a string literal (illegal!). Since C++11 this is enforced by the language, though I believe GCC and Clang still merely warn unfortunately.